# Using GNU Lesser General Public License to develop cloud-based server system

Tags: open-source, licensing, gnu

Let's say we are planning to use an open source project under GNU Lesser General Public License to develop a cloud-based social networking system (a web-based system having horizontaly scalable databases as back end). The completed application will be closed sourced.

So, if we use the source code licensed under GNU Lesser General Public License, or even if we modify it, are we allowed to do that (ie. are we violating the license if our completed product will be closed source.)

The completed application will be commercial based - BUT we are not selling any packaged product - and we will make profits by advertising or download apps, for example.

Comment: This is a legal question and I am not a lawyer, but from my understanding of LGPL it only affects distribution of binaries, not software as a service.  You would be free to use the modified LGPL software without releasing the source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use modified sources for GPL or LGPL software in your cloud service. You only need to publish your modifications if you distribute the binaries.

This "loophole" is closed by the AGPL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your code is just *linked* to LGPL software, it can be distributed under a privative license.

However, if you do *any* modification to the LGPL software you *must* distribute it in source form *if* you distribute it at all. This does not include the part of your code that is only linked to (but not compiled together with) the LPGL software. On the other hand, if you do not distribute it *at all*, you do not have to distribute the sources. This is what some websearch companies do with their modified versions of the linux kernel, and this may be your case if your application is a kind of software-as-a-service application.